# Bing Paid Web Results Only API Returns 403 Error

Tags: c#, bing, http-status-code-403, bing-api

Here is my code for doing a search using the Bing API.  We have the paid version for the Web Only API.  I have read somewhere else that someone else had an issue with the web results only API but surely there has to be someone out there who has gotten this working.

Here is my code that I use.  You will see from the error below the code that it fails at the last line of the code here and gives a 403 error.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
string keyterms = "";
if (Request.QueryString["keywords"] != null) { keyterms = Request.QueryString["keywords"].Trim(); }

var bingContainer = new Bing.BingSearchContainer(new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search"));
var accountKey = "our api";
bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
var query = bingContainer.Web(keyterms, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
var results = query.Execute();
```

Here is the actual error that displays on the screen.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container"><fieldset>
 <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
 <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


Source Error:
Line 39:             bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(accountKey, accountKey);
Line 40:             var query = bingContainer.Web(keyterms, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
Line 41:             var results = query.Execute();
```

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm also getting the same error...